# Double-foreign-key in Hibernate when mapping the same entity twice

Tags: java, hibernate

It is common practice to map the same entity twice or even thrice, every time with a subset of columns needed for processing. I have found that with Hibernate `3.5.1`, every time a `@ManyToOne` or a `@OneToMany` exists in two entities mapping the same table, the foreign key is created twice. This has no impact on MySQL and SQL Server, but Oracle refuses the second creation statement.

Here is an example:

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_STORE", sequenceName = "SEQ_ENTITY")
@Table(name = "ENTITIES")
class Entity {

    //All columns


    //And then.....
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "BRIDGE_TABLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    @OrderBy("id DESC")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Roles>();
}

@Entity
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_STORE", sequenceName = "SEQ_ENTITY")
@Table(name = "ENTITIES")
class EntityListItem {

    //Only a subset of the previous columns


    //And then.....
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "BRIDGE_TABLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    @OrderBy("id DESC")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Roles>();
}
```

Currently, `Role` is designed not to be navigable to `Entity` (otherwise I guess there will be 4 foreign keys).

Here are the statement being issued by Hibernate:

```
create table BRIDGE_TABLE (ENTITY_ID number(19,0) not null, ROLE_ID varchar2(60 char) not null, primary key (ENTITY_ID, ROLE_ID)); //Creates the table
alter table BRIDGE_TABLE add constraint FK47CFB9F0B068EF3F foreign key (ENTITY_ID) references ENTITIES;
alter table BRIDGE_TABLE add constraint FK47CFB9F0B068EF3F foreign key (ENTITY_ID) references ENTITIES;
```

I'm not sure whether this is a Hibernate bug. We cannot currently move to Hibernate 4. Can be this fixed via code or does it need a new Hibernate version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a workaround:

1. Add a `@ForeignKey` annotation with the same FK name to both entities (e.g. `@ForeignKey(name = "FK_TO_ENTITY", inverseName = "FK_TO_ROLE")`)
2. Extend `LocalSessionFactoryBean` like the following:

---

```
@override
public void createDatabaseSchema() throws DataAccessException
{
    logger.info("Creating database schema for Hibernate SessionFactory");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
    final Dialect dialect = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory).getDialect();

    final LinkedHashSet<String> sql = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for (String query : getConfiguration().generateSchemaCreationScript(dialect))
        sql.add(query);

    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public Void doInHibernate(Session session) throws SQLException
        {
            session.doWork(new Work()
            {
                @Override
                public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException
                {
                    PhoenixAnnotationSessionFactoryBean.this.executeSchemaScript(conn, sql.toArray(new String[0]));
                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    });

}
```

---

Reason: the `@ForeignKey` annotation ensures that the FKs will have the same name, hence the SQL statements will be equal each other. The overriden `LSFB` will store the SQL queries needed to create the schema in a `Set` so that no duplicate will be allowed.